# Mailgun route does not get triggered

Tags: email, mailgun

I'm using mailgun with a custom domain.
I have a catch-all route, with a forward action
It doesn't work, the route doesn't get triggered

Mailgun support advised to set up mx records, I did that but it still doesn't work.

They then told me: `I have adjusted your domain's sending IP to aid with message deliverability.` but that didn't solve the problem neither.

Now I don't get any answers anymore from them

Anyone has an idea?

The mails go to the recipient, but the forward route doesn't work. In the logs I can see `routed: null` in de JSON details

Comment: Did you verify that Mailgun receives your mail ?

Comment: Yes, it gets sent to the main recipient and it shows in the logs

Comment: Did you see that they have issues right now ? http://status.mailgun.com/

Comment: Could you include your domain and a screenshot of the routes?